# Pdf does not compile

Tags: errors, pdf, miktex, compiling, texstudio

I am seeing this in `miktex/logs/ pdflatex.log`:

```
starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode ModBook.tex
2018-11-18 08:04:04,769-0800 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2018-11-18 08:04:04,769-0800 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2018-11-18 08:04:05,450-0800 INFO  pdflatex - installing package translator triggered by tex\latex\translator\translator.sty
2018-11-18 08:04:05,453-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2018-11-18 08:04:05,453-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2018-11-18 08:04:05,453-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2018-11-18 08:04:05,453-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1239
2018-11-18 08:04:05,454-0800 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

I am using Miktex/TexStudio and the program does not create a pdf. How do I interpret this message in the above LOGFILE?

MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit

Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems to be linked to the way MiKTeX was installed (not a shared installation, so it can't be run in administarive mode). I guess you should launch the compiler as user.

Comment: I have reinstalled Miktex as "user" not as admin, the question it asks on installation. How do I fix this?  How do I  launch the compiler as a user?


2018-11-19 19:30:38,032-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2018-11-19 19:30:38,033-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2018-11-19 19:30:38,033-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2018-11-19 19:30:38,033-0800 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1270

Comment: Please read but do not add further to the discussion linked below  as you seem to have raised other issues about uninstalling, If you wish to uninstall you need to use the MiKTeX console which has a factory reset function and an uninstall function halfway down the left hand side https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417517/administrative-mode-can-not-be-enabled

Comment: Did you reset or reinstall, are you now able to create a simple pdf without errors ? you can update your question to explain what you have done and show any new errors

Comment: I deleted the previous files (did not use Miktex console). Still unable to use as it keeps asking for Package translator.sty. Despite numerous attempts to install it, it will not. Says it timed out.  I have changed the repository location and have also used the Miktex package manager, however, it refuses to install that package and then asks for it every time I try to create a pdf. I have Windows 10.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall from the console but it wont let me. Says code execution cannot continue because a dll is missing. It seems something is wrong with the installation and I should remove it again. What method should I use to uninstall it? If I can not use the Console, what is the preferred method of removing the software? Should I install the portable version instead?

Comment: There are a few suggestions to try and kickstart a poor installation using windows command line the best one is possibly the latest one august 30 th using two lines here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/187 if that fails the next best suggestion as given in the same thread is manually remove folders  and a registry setting before reinstall, certainly I prefer portable but beware any remnants of the old install may interfere and you need to ensure all paths are correctly set possibly by hand.